# can setContentView get input other than xml layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

what does the following line means

`context.setContentView(mCardScrollView);`

where context is a regular activity (not listActivity)

```
         mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(context);
        ExampleCardScrollAdapter adapter = new ExampleCardScrollAdapter();
        mCardScrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mCardScrollView.activate();
        context.setContentView(mCardScrollView);
```

i'm used to pass xml layout to setContentView, no?

Comment: It means that you are setting view for that activity to show on screen

Comment: it, hmmm sets content view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can setContentView get input other than xml layout?

Yes. [See the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)) for the different methods it has. Besides taking a `layout resource id`, it can also take a `View` (which is what is happening in your example) or a `View` and `params`.

> what does the following line means
>
> context.setContentView(mCardScrollView);

As stated in a comment this is the `View` that will be set on the `Window` for the current `Activity`. If you are inside of an `Activity` method, such as `onCreate()` you do not need to use the `Context` variable since it already has a `Context`.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 `setContentView(...)` methods defined in the API:

1. `setContentView(int layoutResID)` this is the most commonly used one. It taked in an XML layout file id
2. `setContentView(View view)` takes a `View`. In your case it's the `CardScrollView` object
3. `setContentView (View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`same as 2. but also takes in layout parameters.

you can read more about them in the [Activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)